# Apache POI, Excel 2007+ XML, and OSGI

Tags: java, xml, excel, osgi, apache-poi

For a project I'm trying to get Excel XML functionality using Apache POI to work with OSGI.

I've tried the POI ServiceMix bundle, but this was missing the ooxml-schemas jar. Adding the jar to the bundle and including it in the manifest didn't seem to work.

Then I tried to creating wrapper bundles for POI 3.10, but also to no avail. Same error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl not found by org.apache.poi [8]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
... 105 more
```

Subsequent calls lead to the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.&lt;init&gt;(ThemesTable.java:44)
... 93 more
```

XMLBeans is available as a bundle exporting all of its packages, and I've tried the ServiceMix bundle as well as making one out of the jar included with POI 3.10.

Could someone guide me through the process of creating a working OSGI bundle that can handle Excel 2007+ XML documents? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating a single bundle which contains [all of Apache POI + Dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)? No idea if that's "proper" OSGi or not, but that might at least let you get started

Comment: Not proper OSGI, but I tried. Even then it didn't work. There's something else at play here. Of course, I could have made a mistake. I'll give that another try tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Make sure you look at the POI components page to see what you need, and ensure you get everything (POI jars, XMLBeans jar, dom4j, ooxml-schemas, commons etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the classes from `org.apache.poi.ooxml-schemas` call `Class.forName("org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema")`, so you need an import of this package in the manifest of your ooxml-schemas bundle.

I solved it by adding `<DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>` to the configuration of the `maven-bundle-plugin` when building the ooxml-schemas bundle.

Answer (score 1):

We use a bundle that merges `poi`, `poi-ooxml` and `poi-ooxml-schemas` to work around the class loading issue.

For that we use Gradle with [bnd-platform](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform). It allows building and adapting OSGi bundles based on Maven dependencies. Merging JARs to a combined bundle can also be done easily.

I set up an **[example build with an Apache POI bundle](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal/blob/sample-poi/build.gradle)** (and implicitly, its POM-defined dependencies) on GitHub. It's an excerpt from or own configuration for building the complete target platform for an OSGi based application.

You can clone it ([sample-poi](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal/tree/sample-poi) branch) and try it running `./gradlew clean bundles`. Created bundles will be in `build/plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl
  not found by org.apache.poi [8]
```

This means that code within bundle `org.apache.poi` looks for class `SchemaTypeSystemImpl` of package `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema` and can't find it. Given that both class and package look like implementation classes, I'd hypothesize that it's proper and correct that they aren't accessible outside their bundle.

Could you add the complete stack trace for the first exception, so that the call site of the `Class.forName()` will be visible? In all likelihood that's just the downstream of a configuration issue, but it will help narrow it down.

Comment: Thing is, the bundle does export it. I've even explicitly told it to export org.apache.xmlbeans.*.

Comment: You will need to explicitly export `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema`, and either set an explicit import in bundle `org.apache.poi`, or use the `DynamicImport-Package: *` hack in MANIFEST.MF...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the poi library in OSGi by adding the following bundles to the run bundles:
*  [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/4.1.0_1)
*  [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlbeans](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlbeans/3.1.0_1)
*  [commons-collections4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4)
*  [commons-compress](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.19)
*  [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1)
*  [Saxon DOM 8.9.0.4-osgi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/saxon-dom/8.9.0.4-osgi)