# SchemaTypeSystemImpl cannot be found by org.apache.poi.ooxml.schemas

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, apache-poi, eclipse-rcp, xmlbeans

I try to upgrade the xmlbeans from 2.6.0 to 3.1.0 and poi-ooxml-schemas 3.15 to 4.1.1.
I have a target platform file where I add the update site for xmlbeans-3.1.0 and poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.

There are no compiling issues in the code but at runtime I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.SchemaTypeSystemImpl: make sure xbean.jar is on the classpath.
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl cannot be found by org.apache.poi.ooxml.schemas_4.1.1.v20200820-1148
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
```

I also tried to include xmlsec bundle as found [here](http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/org-apache-servicemix-bundles-poi-4-0-0-1-not-osgi-deployable-can-t-resolve-all-dependencies-td5725403.html), but the same result.
Also importing the xmlbeans with Dynamic-import as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273309/apache-poi-excel-2007-xml-and-osgi), it didn't work.

Edit, in TP I have the following:
[image]

Comment: What jars do you have on your *runtime* classpath?

Comment: I have a target platform and do require bundle in my eclipse plugin (added an image).